# Can I publish an app with semitransparent items?

Tags: ios, uiview, colors, uibutton, appstore-approval

I'm building an app that has some semi transparent items: buttons' backgrounds,UIViews' backgrounds and labels' backgrounds. I read that you can't have a transparent app icon and I was wondering if that applied to app items as well. If I can't do that, is there a way to have blurred backgrounds (I know these are allowed instead)?

Comment: Why did you rollback my edit? Your question isn’t about Swift. It’s about whether Apple will accept your app or not.

Comment: please I need help

Comment: But there's nothing to help you with. You have not asked an appropriate programming question. No one here can tell you if Apple will accept your app or not. Try it. See what happens.

Comment: Where should I ask this then? I am sorry

Comment: If Apple didn't permit transparency in their UIs, there would be no apps in the store. You can design your app any way you want. If Apple doesn't permit transparent app icons then that only applies to app icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use transparency in your **app icon**.

That is related ***only*** to the icon - it has nothing to do with any other resources your app uses.